# PDF in book gives impossible answers

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So I have a problem in my book with the following pdf.

$f(x) = \frac32 \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $1≤x≤3$

Otherwise $f(x) = 0$

For any pdf to be valid all probabilities need to be less than one but this obviously yields 150% chance at 1. I made a cdf from this

$F(x) = -\frac{1.5}{x}$ for $1≤x≤3$

and it performs as expected but I was marked wrong by my professor when I used the cdf to find $P[1≤x≤2.5] = .9$ and $P[1.5≤x≤2.5] = .4$. Could someone explain why this answer is incorrect? I don't think this integration is wrong. Even if I integrate from negative infinity to y that still yields the same answer.

Comment: Probabilities are **integrals** of the density function.

Comment: Okay, is the cdf I made wrong then @LordSharktheUnkown? Or did I miscalculate either of the probability ranges mentioned?

Comment: In your calculation of CDF you overlooked that PDF takes value $0$ for $x<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cdf is wrong.  For $1 \le x \le 3$ you should have

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\; dt = \int_1^x \frac{3}{2t^2} \; dt = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{2x}$$
while $F(x) = 0$ for $x < 1$ and $F(x) = 1$ for $x > 3$.